# Prevent closing of a form

Tags: vb6

How can i avoid closing a form if by mistake cross is clicked

Comment: Just ask in `QueryUnload`. People rarely click the close button by mistake.

Answer (score 10):

Handle this in the Form's QueryUnload event.  There's an UnloadMode parameter and a Cancel Parameter:

```
Private Sub Form_QueryUnload(Cancel As Integer, UnloadMode As Integer)

    If UnloadMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True

End Sub
```

For more info on the QueryUnload event, see the [MSDN VB6 Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445536(VS.60).aspx) or check out [this article](http://visualbasic.freetutes.com/learn-vb6-advanced/lesson6/p5.html).

Comment: +1. An alternative source of info about QueryUnload is the VB6 language reference: on MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445536(VS.60).aspx

Comment: Thanks MarkJ.  Funny how page 1 of google search for vb6 queryunload event doesn't list the msdn page...